# Swift ios facebook login crashes app if user cancel login

Tags: ios, swift, facebook

I am using the following code to login with facebook:

```
@IBAction func fbLoginBtnDidTouch(sender: AnyObject) {
        let fbLoginManager : FBSDKLoginManager = FBSDKLoginManager()
        fbLoginManager.logInWithReadPermissions(["email"], fromViewController: self) { (result, error) -> Void in
            if (error == nil){
                let fbloginresult : FBSDKLoginManagerLoginResult = result
                if(fbloginresult.grantedPermissions.contains("email"))
                {
                    self.getFBUserData()
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

AppDelegate:

```
func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject: AnyObject]?) -> Bool {
  FBSDKApplicationDelegate.sharedInstance().application(application, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions: launchOptions)
}

func application(application: UIApplication, openURL url: NSURL, sourceApplication: String?, annotation: AnyObject) -> Bool {
        return FBSDKApplicationDelegate.sharedInstance().application(application, openURL: url, sourceApplication: sourceApplication, annotation: annotation)
    }
```

This will launch FB in a webview. If the user accept the app from the FB account it will return to the app as expected.

But if the user clicks on **NO** or clicks the **Done** button in the webview with FB the app will crash saying (*fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value*)

Marking this line:

```
if(fbloginresult.grantedPermissions.contains("email"))
```

So why does the app crash if the user clicks on No or Done?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

First check if user canceled login. App crashed because there are no granted permissions. [FBSDKLoginManagerLoginResult](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/ios/current/class/FBSDKLoginManagerLoginResult/)

```
if (error == nil){
   let fbloginresult : FBSDKLoginManagerLoginResult = result
   if result.isCancelled {
      return
   }
   if(fbloginresult.grantedPermissions.contains("email"))
     {
         self.getFBUserData()
     }
}
```

Comment: Yes the app crashes when I cancel the login, either by clicking NO or on the done button